# Online algorithm to find median with sublinear space complexity

Tags: algorithm, selection

Got a task to plan a algorithm/data-structure that recieved values one by one and can give the current median while asked.
It should support instertion of value with time complexity of logn and output the median with constant time complexity.

Is there a way to do this with sublinear space complexity?
Thank you.

Comment: Pure algorithmic questions may suit https://cs.stackexchange.com better, but make sure to read their how to ask page before asking.

Comment: Also - no spelling error. "median", not "midean".

Comment: I won't give the answer because... I'm not sure if this is good for stack overflow, and answering bad questions may attract even more bad questions to stack overflow.

Comment: This is a classic heap problem, take a look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-stream-of-integers-running-integers/

Comment: @hbejgel he asks about possibility of the sub-linear *space* complexity

Comment: Using heaps to calculate rolling medians is O(logn) for insertion of the new member and O(1) to calculate the new median.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already seen `n` numbers, each of those can be made the current median by adding some more numbers. So it is impossible to find a solution with sub-linear space complexity.

Comment: That what I thought. Will it change if i'll know the total number of input items?

Comment: In this case you could reduce the memory requirement because you can throw out numbers that cannot become the current median any more but it is still O(n).

Answer (score 0):

if you are fine with *estimation* instead of *finding* then here is the [solution](https://khamenya.notion.site/Guessing-a-real-number-by-binary-response-5ba9bd997f514ec4b4cdc2ae2322f39d) for online estimation with about O(log(n)) convergence,
O(1) memory and
O(1) operations per incremental step.